# textvariable not found in a def

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code :

```py
from tkinter import *

def mine():
    global textVar
    textVar = StringVar()
    textVar.set('Text')


root = Tk()

root.title('Miner v1.0')
root.geometry('400x240')

miningButton = Button(root, text='Mine', command=mine)
miningButton.pack()

mainLabel = Label(root, textvariable=textVar)
mainLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I have made `textVar` a global variable but the `mainLabel` it don't find it, it says that it is undefined. But when the `textVar` is outside the `def` it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you never execute the `mine` function, so `textVar` variable has never existed. You can just create the variable outside the function.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title('Miner v1.0')
root.geometry('400x240')

textVar = StringVar()
def mine():
    textVar.set('Text')

miningButton = Button(root, text='Mine', command=mine)
miningButton.pack()

mainLabel = Label(root, textvariable=textVar)
mainLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nurqm, I have the answer:

````py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title('Miner v1.0')
root.geometry('400x240')

textVar = StringVar()
def mine():
    textVar.set('Text')

miningButton = Button(root, text='Mine', command=mine)
miningButton.pack()

mainLabel = Label(root, textvariable=textVar)
mainLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Pls, don't post this as your answer instead mark @Nurqm answer as accepted.

Comment: How can I do that please ? I'm new on Stack :)

Comment: Just hit the tick mark beside his answer.